# Read Excel sheet with Apache POI without header using for loop

Tags: java, apache-poi

I want to read Excel file without a header using for loop and want to use that data to pass to another method. I'm unable to do so. Without header works fine.

```
@DataProvider(name = "inputData")

public static Object[][] getExcelData() throws IOException {

        inputStream = new FileInputStream(Constants.TEST_DATA);

        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);

        sheet = workbook.getSheet("CRMData");

        int rowCount = sheet.getLastRowNum() + 1;

        int columnCount = sheet.getRow(0).getLastCellNum();

        Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount][columnCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
            row = sheet.getRow(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                cell = row.getCell(j);
                data[i][j] = cell.getStringCellValue();

            }
        }

        workbook.close();
        return data;
    }
```

I expect this method to fetch only test data, not the header, and pass that data to my test case for execution.

Comment: Where the selenium code related?

Comment: @Test(dataProvider = "inputData")

public static void testData(String username, String password) {
  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", Constants.CHROME_DRIVER);
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
  driver.manage().window().maximize();
  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.get("https://url.com/");
  driver.findElement(By.name("email")).sendKeys(username);
  driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys(password);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='ui fluid large blue submit button']")).click();
 }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to skip header means top row of your excel file initialize value of i for the for loop with 1 which is responsible to traverse within rows. Top row used to have index value 0. So your for loop code for row and columns should be like this.

```
 Object[][] data = new Object[rowCount][columnCount];
        for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
            XSSFRow row = sheet.getRow(i);

            for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
                XSSFCell cell = row.getCell(j);
                data[i][j] = cell.getStringCellValue();
                System.out.println(data[i][j]);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You mean as in:

```java
for (int i = 1; i < rowCount; i++) {
    row = sheet.getRow(i);

    for (int j = 0; j < columnCount; j++) {
        cell = row.getCell(j);
        data[i - 1][j] = cell.getStringCellValue();
    }
}
```

That is, start from the second row?